# Facing issues when adding angular universal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am working with angular 12.2.11 and am trying to add angular universal using the following commands.

`ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`

the **nguniversal** is installed successfully.

after that, I have build my angular application using the following command and the build was also successful.

`npm run build:ssr`

but when I start the ssr using the following command it returns an error related to jQuery.

`npm run serve:ssr`

Here is the error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement')

is there any solution for this? I don't know what I am doing wrong please correct me.

I want to add `@nguniversal` into my angular application

- angular cli version  12.2.11
- nguniversal/express-engine version 7.0.2
- jQuery version 3.6.0